# Compare two list of values A and B, if there any value equal to B in the list A

Tags: excel, vba

How to compare two list of values `A` and `B`, if there any value in `B` equals to a value in the list `A`, Then write the row number of the column `A` in front of the value in the column `B` using Excel/macro/VBA.

Comment: Could you give us an example and your current code?

Comment: Can you edit your question with this example?

Comment: It sounds as though you are wanting to write VBA code to run in Excel, not vb.net code in Visual Studio. If that is the case, please edit your question to replace the vb.net tag with vba-excel.

Comment: yea thats the case i want it from vba-excel not vb.net can you please help me

Comment: @pop: If you edit your question to replace the vb.net tag with excel-vba, you question will be seen by people who are familiar with excel-vba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this VBA:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim strValueB As String, strValueA As String

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Do
        i = i + 1: j = 0
        strValueB = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value    '2 -> Column B
        If (strValueB = "") Then Exit Do

        Do
            j = j + 1
            strValueA = ws.Cells(j, 1).Value    '1 -> Column A
            If (strValueA = "") Then
                k = 0
                Exit Do
            ElseIf (strValueB = strValueA) Then
                k = j
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

        If (k > 0) Then
            ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = k    '3-> Column C
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you soo much!!! thats the exact code i was looking for!! :) :) thank u again!!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the following formula

```
= MATCH(ListAVariable, $B:$B:,0)
```

Put this in Column `C` - then use

```
=CONCATENATE(BX, " ", CX)
```

In column `D`

Comment: you don't need a VBA function for this - it would take more time. LOOK UP - INDEX() MATCH() MATCH() scenarios on youtube

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zGRjZ.png  but i must use vba/macro not excel formula

Comment: @blackwood i replaced it but stil didn`t get what i need :(